# python jsocket RuntimeError

Tags: python, jsocket

I'm trying to write a JSocket server in python using [jsocket](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsocket/1.5). I've used the example code from the [jsocket](http://pythonhosted.org/jsocket/) and modified it so that the server replies as soon after it receives a message from the client. When my client tries to receive the response in "client.read_obj()" I get an exception. My code and the stacktrace below:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import jsocket
    import logging

    logger = logging.getLogger("jsocket.testJSocket")

    class MyFactoryThread(jsocket.ServerFactoryThread):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MyFactoryThread, self).__init__()
            self.timeout = 2.0

        def _process_message(self, obj):  
            if obj!='':
                if obj ['message'] == 'new connection':
                    logger.info("new connection")
                    self.socket.send_obj({"dbResult": "result"})
                else:
                    logger.info(obj)
                    self.socket.send_obj({"dbResult": "result"})


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import time
        import jsocket

        server = jsocket.ServerFactory(MyFactoryThread)
        server.timeout = 2.0
        server.start()

        time.sleep(1)
        client = jsocket.JsonClient()
        client.connect()
        client.send_obj({"message":"new connection"})

        client.read_obj()

        client.close()

        server.stop()
        server.join()
```

Stacktrace:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~/programming/lights/comms $ sudo python testJSocket.py 
    [2016-02-11 20:28:54,475][DEBUG][tserver][start] Threaded Server has been started.
    [2016-02-11 20:28:55,479][DEBUG][jsocket_base][accept_connection] connection accepted, conn socket (127.0.0.1,39001)
    [2016-02-11 20:28:55,481][INFO][jsocket_base][connect] ...Socket Connected
    [2016-02-11 20:28:55,485][INFO][testJSocket][_process_message] new connection
    [2016-02-11 20:28:55,486][INFO][tserver][run] client connection broken, closing socket
    [2016-02-11 20:28:55,487][DEBUG][jsocket_base][_close_connection] closing the connection socket
    [2016-02-11 20:28:55,488][DEBUG][jsocket_base][_close_socket] closing main socket
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "testJSocket.py", line 39, in <module>
        client.read_obj()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsocket/jsocket_base.py", line 74, in read_obj
        size = self._msg_length()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsocket/jsocket_base.py", line 69, in _msg_length
        d = self._read(4)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsocket/jsocket_base.py", line 65, in _read
        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
    RuntimeError: socket connection broken
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was referencing the wrong socket. Correct code:

```
        def _process_message(self, obj):

            if obj!='':
                if obj ['message'] == 'new connection':
                    logger.info("new connection")
                    self.send_obj({"dbResult": "result"})
                else:
                    logger.info(obj)
                    self.send_obj({"dbResult": "result"})
```